# Realm Android index of objects

Tags: android, realm

How can I change the order or index of Realm object in the android studio??

I want to change the order of the objects, I cleared the class and tried to insert a new one, Is that the solution. Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just inserted a column `sort_order` and updated that each time.

Works perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using findAll() method you can use findAllSorted() and you can also give ASCENDING or DESCENDING order.

From Realm documentation:

> findAllSorted(java.lang.String[] fieldNames, Sort[] sortOrders)
>
> Finds all objects that fulfill the query conditions and sorted by
>   specific field names.
>
> Parameters:
>
> fieldNames - an array of field names to sort by.
>
> sortOrders - how to sort the field names.
>
> Returns: a RealmResults containing objects. If no objects match the
>   condition, a list with zero objects is returned.

Comment: Actually, I have a recycler view with drag option, When I change the positions I have to save the changes to the Realm database also.

Thanks for your response.

Comment: Realm does not guarantee an order for the underlying data which is why you should provide a sorting if that is required. In your case you probably need to add a `sortIndex` to your objects you can change and then sort on that.

Comment: I already did that, It works perfectly. Thanks for your replay.

Comment: How to add the auto-increment field to Realm.

Comment: Is it possible? Please help me.